# How do I group by and "prefer" a row

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by

I simply want to have a SQL statement to `GROUP BY`, however I would want it to try and choose one row if that row is available.

For example, I have this statement:

```
SELECT *
FROM `translations`
WHERE `lang` = "pl" OR `lang` = "en"
GROUP BY `key`
```

In this statement, I am trying to select all where the `lang` is `pl`, and only get the `en` results if there is no result for the equivalent `pl` row.

`key` is the column which is the same over multiple `lang`'s.

If I run the above statement however, all the results will be where the `lang` is `en`, and I understand why this is however it isn't the behaviour I want, and I am unsure how to adjust it.

I know how to do this programmatically, however thought it would be neater with just SQL.

Comment: What do you mean by `GROUP BY`?

Comment: I would build it differently, do a COALESCE between the primary table where lang is `en` and a secondary table that might match where lang is `pl`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can phrase this as a `union all` statement.  My assumption is that the `key`,`lang` pair uniquely identifies one row (otherwise you can still do the `group by` to get one row per key).

The idea is to select all rows with `lang = 'pl'`.  Then select the rows where `lang = 'en'` that have no corresponding row with `'pl'` for the same key:

```
SELECT *
FROM translations
WHERE lang = 'pl'
union all
SELECT *
FROM translations
WHERE lang = 'en' and
      `key` not in (select `key` from translations where lang = 'pl')
```

Comment: Thanks, this seems like quite fitting!

Answer (score 0):

Not an optimal, but it should give the desired result :

```
SELECT a.* 
FROM 
(
SELECT * FROM `translations` where `lang` = "pl"
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM `translations` a where `lang` = "en"
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT NULL FROM `translations` b WHERE b.lang="pl")
)a GROUP BY `key`
```

Answer (score 0):

I would do it like this:

```
SELECT COALESCE(`translation_foreign`.`value`, `translations`.`value`) AS `value`
FROM `translations`
LEFT JOIN `translation` as `translations_foreign` ON 
             translations_foreign.key = translations.key AND 
             translations_foreign.lang = "pl"
WHERE lang = "en"
GROUP BY `translations`.`key`
```